# Laravel 5 Route with multiple ID’s

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I would like to pass two sets of ID’s into a route.

The first ID is that of the authenticated user so for example 3 and the second is that of a candidate.

So what I would like it to do is: **vault/3/candidates/120**

Here is the route I want to have:

```
Route::get('vault/{id}/candidates/{id}', 'CandidateController@centreCandidatesShow');
```

Using:

```
public function centreCandidatesShow($id)
{
    $candidate = Candidate::with('qualification')->find($id);

    return view('vault.show', compact('candidate'));
}
```

Could someone let me know if this is possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`routes.php`:

```
Route::get('vault/{userId}/candidates/{candidateId}', 'CandidateController@centreCandidatesShow');
```

`CandidatesController.php`:

```
public function centreCandidatesShow($userId, $canidateId)
{
    $candidate = Candidate::with('qualification')->find($canidateId);
    $user = User::find($userId);

    return view('vault.show', compact('candidate'));
}
```

#### Named routes

I highly recommend using named routes.

```
Route::get('vault/{userId}/candidates/{candidateId}', [
    'as' => 'candidates.show', 
    'uses' => 'CandidateController@centreCandidatesShow'
]);
```

This will not only help you generate url's  but also helps when passing parameters!

Example:

`<a href="{{ route('candidates.show', $userId, $candidateId) }}">Link to candidate</a>`

This will provide the link and pass in the parameters!

You can even redirect to a route from your controller!

`return redirect()->route('candidates.show', $userId, $candidateId);`

---

## Explanation:

You can put whatver you want as route parameters. Anything inside curly brackets are considered a valid parameter. Another example would be:

```
Route::get('country/{country}/city/{city}/street/{street}/zip{zip}', 'AddressController@show');
```

In your AddressController@show you would accept these parameters, in order.

`public function show($country, $city, $street, $zip) {..}`

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the reply very insightful and helpful! :)

Comment: When using the route in the link, you should use an array, as the 2nd argument `<a href="{{URL::route('admin-photo-delete', [$id, $photo->id] )}}">Delete Photo</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the ids in an array

```
Route::get('vault/{userId}/candidates/{candidateId}', [
    'as' => 'candidates.show', 
    'uses' => 'CandidateController@centreCandidatesShow'
]);

<a href="{{ route('candidates.show', ['userId'=$userId, 'candidateId'=$candidateId]) }}">Link to candidate</a>
```

[laravel 5 route passing two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382650/laravel-5-route-passing-two-parameters)